# Como ocultar una URL o el USER: PASS de la conexion BDs. en Android studio

Tags: android

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en android y una base de datos de mongo, la quiero publicar en la playstore, pero en cuestion de seguridad quisiera que mi URL de conexion o mi user:pass no sean accesibles o esten ocultos por si alguien descompila mi app, no pueda ver esos datos
actualmente la conexion la realizo asi: .... la pregunta es? que puedo hacer para que esta informacion sensible no sea vista por nadie?

```
private static final String URLBBDD = "localhost";
private static final int PUERTOBBDD = 27017;
private static final String USUARIO = "usuario";
private static final String CONTRASENNA = "contrasenna";

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(URLBBDD, PUERTOBBDD, USUARIO, CONTRASENA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal por seguridad y para preservar información sensible, evitando que esta sea obtenida y sea usada de forma incorrecta , es que la comunicación sea enviada de forma cifrada a un servidor para determinar si tienes acceso o no.

Aunque existe una opción que recomienda Google para evitar que nuestra información sea obtenida mediante ingeniería inversa, y que actualmente es usado para "esconder" API Keys mediante el plugin "Secrets":

[Esconder tus API Keys en Android](https://youtu.be/X8lYNW_Or2o)

[Complemento Secrets Gradle para Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin?hl=es-419)

https://github.com/google/secrets-gradle-plugin

---

Hay que tomar en cuenta que no puede ser imposible se pueda obtener la información, por lo tanto, tú debes evaluar usar este método o no.

Dentro de tu archivo `local.properties` ubicado en la raíz de tu proyecto (si no existe lo creas), puedes agregar los valores que deseas "esconder"

```
URLBBDD=localhost
PUERTOBBDD = 27017
USUARIO=usuario
CONTRASENNA=contrasenna
```

En tu archivo app/build.gradle agrega:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.android.secrets-gradle-plugin"
```

y también

```
secrets {
    defaultPropertiesFileName = 'local.properties'
}
```

En tu archivo build.gradle agrega la dependencia dentro del bloque "dependencias" de "buildscript":

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        ...         
        classpath "com.google.android:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }
}
```

Al construir tu proyecto, estos valores se agregarán a tu clase BuildConfig.java

```
public final class BuildConfig {

  public static final String URLBBDD = "localhost";
  public static final String PUERTOBBDD = "27017";
  public static final String USUARIO = "usuario";
  public static final String CONTRASENNA = "contrasenna";
}
```

por lo tanto, solo se obtendrán al compilar y podrás usarlos en tu proyecto de esta forma, ejemplo:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(BuildConfig.URLBBDD, BuildConfig.PUERTOBBDD, BuildConfig.USUARIO, BuildConfig.CONTRASENNA);
```